# How to Compare Multiple lists of tuples in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

How can I compare Multiple lists of tuples like this:

```
[[(1,2), (3,6), (5,3)], [(1,5), (3,5)], [(2,1), (1,8), (3,9)]]
```

The output should be:

```
[(1,2), (1,5), (1,8)],[(3,6), (3,5), (3,9)]
```

It means that i want just those values whose **x-axis** value matches others.
(5,3) and (2,1) should be discarded!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: what happens to (5, 3) and (2, 1)?

Comment: @gnibbler I think the OP means that he only want to keep the tuples whose zeroth index is shared by at least another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible Option

```
>>> def group(seq):
    for k, v in groupby(sorted(chain(*seq), key = itemgetter(0)), itemgetter(0)):
        v = list(v)
        if len(v) > 1:
            yield v


>>> list(group(some_list))
[[(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 8)], [(3, 6), (3, 5), (3, 9)]]
```

Another Popular Option

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def group(seq):
    some_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for e in chain(*seq):
        some_dict[e[0]].append(e)
    return (v for v in some_dict.values() if len(v) > 1)

>>> list(group(some_list))
[[(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 8)], [(3, 6), (3, 5), (3, 9)]]
```

So which of them fairs better with the example data?

```
>>> def group_sort(seq):
    for k, v in groupby(sorted(chain(*seq), key = itemgetter(0)), itemgetter(0)):
        v = list(v)
        if len(v) > 1:
            yield v


>>> def group_hash(seq):
    some_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for e in chain(*seq):
        some_dict[e[0]].append(e)
    return (v for v in some_dict.values() if len(v) > 1)

>>> t1_sort = Timer(stmt="list(group_sort(some_list))", setup = "from __main__ import some_list, group_sort, chain, groupby")
>>> t1_hash = Timer(stmt="list(group_hash(some_list))", setup = "from __main__ import some_list, group_hash,chain, defaultdict")
>>> t1_hash.timeit(100000)
3.340240917954361
>>> t1_sort.timeit(100000)
0.14324535970808938
```

And with a much larger random list

```
>>> some_list = [[sample(range(1000), 2) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(100)]
>>> t1_sort.timeit(100)
1.3816694363194983
>>> t1_hash.timeit(1000)
34.015403087978484
>>>
```

Comment: Using sorted makes this O(n log n). It's possible to solve it in O(n)

Comment: @gnibbler: Hashing vs sorting, always in war

Comment: @gnibbler: Sorting makes it 25 times faster than hashing

Comment: That's fine if the size of the input data is constrained. log(n) is quite small, so you may need quite a large input to see the sorting algorithm fall behind

Comment: PEP8 says not to put spaces for `key=itemgetter(0)`

Comment: All in a list comprehension is probably faster still `[v for v in (list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(chain(*seq), key=itemgetter(0)), itemgetter(0))) if len(v) > 1]`

Comment: @gnibbler: Even for a considerable larger list, sorting is faster, (check my updated)

Comment: You're actually only timing how long it takes to create the generator for group_sort(). When I time `list(group_sort())` it's 3 times slower than `group_hash()`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something link this:

```
l = [[(1,2), (3,6), (5,3)], [(1,5), (3,5)], [(2,1), (1,8), (3,9)]]
output = [l[0][0], l[1][0], l[2][1]], [l[0][1], l[1][1], l[2][2]]
```

Comment: The OP probably has a different list, as the one given above is just an example.

Comment: (5,3) and (2,1) should be discarded!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L=[[(1,2), (3,6), (5,3)], [(1,5), (3,5)], [(2,1), (1,8), (3,9)]]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> p = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in chain.from_iterable(L):
...  p[i[0]].append(i)
... 
>>> p = {k:v for k,v in p.items() if len(v)>1}
>>> p.values()
[[(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 8)], [(3, 6), (3, 5), (3, 9)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

well this works:

```
>>> l=[[(1,2), (3,6), (5,3)], [(1,5), (3,5)], [(2,1), (1,8), (3,9)]]
>>> [[t for t in [i for sub in l for i in sub] if t[0]==1]]+[[t for t in [i for sub in l for i in sub] if t[0]==3]]
[[(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 8)], [(3, 6), (3, 5), (3, 9)]]
```

Or, without repetition:

```
>>> flat=[i for sub in l for i in sub]
>>> [[t for t in flat if t[0]==1]]+[[t for t in flat if t[0]==3]] 
[[(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 8)], [(3, 6), (3, 5), (3, 9)]]
```