# How to extract the specific tuples from lists in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

How can I extract the specific tuples from the lists given below:

```
[[[(1, 4)]], [[(1, 3)], [(5, 4)]], [[(1, 2)]]]
```

I want to extract the tuples with SAME x-axis, like:

```
[(1,4), (1,3), (1,2)]
```

whereas (5,4) should be discarded.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You'll be more likely to get helpful answers if you show that you've already done some of the work yourself (both because other people are more likely to try to help you out, and because it can show more details of your situation.

Comment: How is this different to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15017497/78845)?

Comment: @ Johnsyweb: I am new to python! trying to make a project of mine! I need to extract these values for my further calculations! list in list scares me alot.

Comment: @ Blckknght: I have used nested loops to extract them and then compare values, but this makes execution very slow! I want a fast extraction method so that I may get and compare values from a sheet of 16K rows.

Comment: Perhaps if you share your nested loops with us we may be able to help you optimise them.

Comment: what do you mean with `"sheet with 16K rows"`? you should tell us whats the initial input (excel sheet?) and what are you trying to achieve...because there is probably a better/faster way to do it all together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flatten a list, you should always use itertools.chain. In this case, you have to apply nested `chain` to create a flat list of tuples

```
>>> l=[[[(1, 4)]], [[(1, 3)], [(5, 4)]], [[(1, 2)]]]
>>> [e for e in chain(*chain(*l)) if e[0] == 1]
[(1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: You should actually use `chain.from_iterable(l)` vs `chain(*l)`. Faster. A list comprehension is also faster vs `chain(*l)` but `chain.from_iterable(l)` is faster than a LC. See the timing.

Answer (score 0):

Well you added an additional depth of list compared to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017497/how-to-compare-multiple-lists-of-tuples-in-python)

So, this list comprehension works:

```
>>> l=[[[(1, 4)]], [[(1, 3)], [(5, 4)]], [[(1, 2)]]]
>>> def flat1(l): return [i for sub in l for i in sub]
...
>>> [t for t in flat1(flat1(l)) if t[0]==1]
[(1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2)]
```

---

The list comprehension method of flattening a list of lists if about the same speed (slightly faster) as `itertools.chain(*l)`.

If you want to use itertools for speed, you should use `chain.from_iterable(l)` instead.

Here is the timing:

```
import timeit
n=1000000

c1='''
def f1(l):
    return [e for e in itertools.chain(*itertools.chain(*l)) if e[0] == 1]

l1=f1([[[(1, 4)]], [[(1, 3)], [(5, 4)]], [[(1, 2)]]])
'''    

c2='''
def f2(l):
    def flat1(l): return [i for sub in l for i in sub]
    return [t for t in flat1(flat1(l)) if t[0]==1]

l1=f2([[[(1, 4)]], [[(1, 3)], [(5, 4)]], [[(1, 2)]]])
'''

c3='''
def f1(l):
    flat1=itertools.chain.from_iterable
    return [e for e in flat1(flat1(l)) if e[0] == 1]

l1=f1([[[(1, 4)]], [[(1, 3)], [(5, 4)]], [[(1, 2)]]])
'''              

t1=timeit.timeit(stmt=c1,setup='import itertools',number=n)
t2=timeit.timeit(stmt=c2,number=n)
t3=timeit.timeit(stmt=c3,setup='import itertools',number=n)

print '          chain(*l):',t1,'seconds'
print ' list comprehension:',t2,'seconds'
print 'chain.from_iterable:',t3,'seconds'
```

Prints:

```
          chain(*l): 4.32919406891 seconds
 list comprehension: 4.32601380348 seconds
chain.from_iterable: 3.14966917038 seconds
```